# How do I get backlink info on a link in an automated way?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

I would like to build a mini [Ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com/), where I can get some basic stuff (like Domain Authority, Page Rank and # of Backlinks) to any link I want.

Ideally, I would think, the simplest way would be to just ping the Google Search API and get that info. But, it seems the [Google Web Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/) is deprecated, and [Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) seems to be focused on allowing me to search within 1 site or a small handful of sites. Plus the rate limit of 100 queries per day, is kinda ridiculous.

What's an alternative way for me to go about getting access to that data that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagerank is no longer available to the public, Google has now switched off the API.

Domain Authority is not a Google Metric - service like Moz.com and Ahrefs.com construct their own metrics to try and 'weight' websites. You'll only get access via their APIs.

Number of backlinks you can try to get from Search Console. This is only accessible via their 'download latest links' csvs however. There is no API access beyond querying your search analytics.

Comment: Interesting....so how does Ahrefs build their index? Manually crawling the web like Google?

Comment: Moz, Ahrefs and Majestic are just a few companies that do broad web crawls using similar behaviour to Google. The size and quality of their databases compared to Google's own varies and each competes to try and build it to be as close as possible (hint: It's not just size, Google's is smaller than you think). They build vast indexes of backlinks in order to perform these estimates. There is no feesible way to do this without building a huge database.